# Flutter: Keep user logged in after app closes and reopen

Tags: authentication, flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner and requesting help. I tried to find the answer but sadly cannot find the answer that I'm looking for. I'm building an app where users can see the homepage and other parts of the app when they are not logged in. This part I have working but only when I close the app and restart it I need to log in again. This is of course not ideal. I tried to look for the `SharedPreferences` but all examples I can find are with a login function for the whole app and I can't figure out how to get it working in my app. Below is the code I have so far. All help is appreciated and thank you all in advance!

(Apologies for posting so much code but it might help!)

> Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/firebaseauthservice.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/users.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
           child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Rèboo',
            theme: new ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
              home:HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

> HomePage.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/authenticate/signin.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/authenticate/signout.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/models/drawerlogin.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/models/drawerlogout.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/firebaseauthservice.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/users.dart';

class DrawerItem {
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon);
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final drawerItems = [
    new DrawerItem("Rèboo", Icons.home),
    new DrawerItem("Inbox", Icons.mail_outline),
    new DrawerItem("Profile", Icons.person_outline),
    new DrawerItem("Reservations", Icons.event_note),
    new DrawerItem("Favorites", Icons.favorite_border),
    new DrawerItem("Vouchers", Icons.card_giftcard),
    new DrawerItem("Invite Friends", Icons.person_add),
    new DrawerItem("Settings", Icons.settings),
    new DrawerItem("FAQ", Icons.help_outline),
    new DrawerItem("Terms & Conditions", Icons.assignment),
    new DrawerItem("Sign out", Icons.exit_to_app),
  ];

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;
  var _setIcon = Icons.person;
  var drawer;
  String uid;

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new Reboo();
      case 1:
        return new Inbox();
      case 2:
        return new Profile();
      case 3:
        return new Reservations();
      case 4:
        return new Favorites();
      case 5:
        return new Vouchers();
      case 6:
        return new InviteFriends();
      case 7:
        return new Settings();
      case 8:
        return new Faq();
      case 9:
        return new TermsAndConditions();
      case 10:
        return new SignOut();
      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }


  _onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
    if (_selectedDrawerIndex == 0) {
      setState(() => _setIcon = Icons.person);
    } else {
      setState(() => _setIcon = Icons.arrow_back);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var drawerOptions = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(new ListTile(
        leading: new Icon(
          d.icon,
          color: Color(0xFF008577),
        ),
        title: new Text(d.title),
        selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
        onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
      ));
    }
    final auth = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false);
    if (auth != null) {
      drawer = DrawerLogin();
    } else {
      drawer = DrawerLogout();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(_setIcon),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_selectedDrawerIndex == 0) {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                } else {
                  setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = 0);
                  setState(() => _setIcon = Icons.person);
                }
              },
              tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
            );
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF008577),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Company()),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[drawer, new Column(children: drawerOptions)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

> FirebaseAuthService.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/users.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/database.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }


  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }


  // sign with email & password

Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password); 
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  }catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}

  // register with email & password

Future registerForm(String email, String password, String birthday, String address, String fullName, String phone) async {
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    // creat a new document in the database for the user with the uid
    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(email, birthday, address, fullName, phone);

    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  }catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}

  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
            (FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid,
      );
  // GET UID
  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    return (await _auth.currentUser()).uid;
  }
  Future getCurrentUser() async {
    return await _auth.currentUser();
  }

  //sign out
  Future signOut() async{
    try{
      return await _auth.signOut();
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

SignIn.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/authenticate/register.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/home/homepage.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/constants.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/loading.dart';
import 'package:reboo1/services/firebaseauthservice.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  SignIn({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //global key
  bool loading = false;

  // text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF008577),
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text('Sign in to Rèboo'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  label: Text('Register'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Register()),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey, //global key
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                      decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                          hintText: 'Email address'),
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email address' : null,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() => email = val);
                      }),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration:
                        textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val.length < 8 ? 'Enter valid password' : null,
                    obscureText: true,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => password = val);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.purple[400],
                    child:
                        Text('Sign in', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        setState(() => loading = true);
                        dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email, password);
                        if (result == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            error =
                                'Could not sign in with those credentials. Please register an account.';
                            setState(() => loading = false);
                          });
                        } else {

                          setState(() => loading = false);
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                          );
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                  Text(
                    error,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have provided a dummy implementation but this is the legit way to tackle this. If you want to search on google, search for keyword firebase onAuthChanged, and read about it. No local storage is required and the most simple and secure way to handle your requirement.

```
StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return print("getting data");
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                !snapshot.hasData) {
              return print("no user found");
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                snapshot.hasData)
              {
                return print(snapshot.data.currentuser);
              }
            else
              return null;
          },
```

Comment: thank you! this helped me in the right direction and I fixed the problem! Because of your answer, I started searching and came to the problem in my code!

Comment: you can use shared pref to store when the user once log into the account

Comment: @Ismail it would be better if you can mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You could save some sort of data to your shared preferences, then when a user opens the app you could retrieve that data from the shared preferences to determine if the user should already be logged in or not. That data could be the users bearer token and expiry date for instance. This could look something like this:

Save data to shared preferences:

```
Future storeTokenPropertiesToPreferences(
  TokenProperties accessTokenProperties, refreshTokenProperties) async {
final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
preferences.setString(
  _preferencesLocation,
  json.encode(
    {
      'accessToken': accessTokenProperties?.value,
      'refreshToken': refreshTokenProperties?.value,
      'accessTokenExpiresAt':
          accessTokenProperties?.expiresAt?.toIso8601String(),
      'refreshTokenExpiresAt':
          refreshTokenProperties?.expiresAt?.toIso8601String(),
    },
  ),
);
```

Retrieve data:

```
  Future<TokenProperties> _tokenPropertiesFromPreferences(
  String tokenName) async {
final _userData = await _getPreferences();

try {
  final value = _userData[tokenName];
  final expiresAt = DateTime.parse(_userData['${tokenName}ExpiresAt']);
  final lifeTime = expiresAt.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;

  return (value == null || expiresAt == null)
      ? null
      : TokenProperties(value, lifeTime);
} catch (e) {
  await _loggingService.log(LoggingMethod.ERROR,
      'Could not get token properties from preferences for token $tokenName. Got exception: $e');
  return null;
}


  Future<Map<String, Object>> _getPreferences() async {
final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (!preferences.containsKey(_preferencesLocation)) return null;

return json.decode(preferences.getString(_preferencesLocation))
    as Map<String, Object>;
}
```

You could obviously change out the object properties to whatever you need, this is just an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where in my code I would put these? I'm a real beginner and have no idea :)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @UTKARSH Sharma I found out that the user is not logged out but the problem was in my own code. I found the below code which helped me solve my problem:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print("user is logged in");
        //navigate to home page using Navigator Widget
      } else {
        print("user is not logged in");
         //navigate to sign in page using Navigator Widget
      }
    });
  }
```

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to mess up with local storage to save user's detail.As Firebase itself store user's detail in local storage.You just need to call .currentUser() method of FirebaseAuth class object when your app starts. If the current user is null then load Login Page otherwise your Main Page. Just like that;

```
Future loadUser() async {
    FirebaseUser _tempUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    if (_tempUser != null)
    //  goto MainPage(mainUser:_tempUser);
    } else
    //  goto LoginPage;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. That is what I don't want because and causing me a lot of problems because users that are not logged in and enter my app for the first time should also be able to see the main page.